# Bulk insert MongoDB - Pymongo limit issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert

I was trying to bulk insert documents to MongoDB with Pymongo if no match on already existing ids (sourceID). However, most of my documents include quite long texts and therefore cannot be inserted - I am not sure whether this is due to a size limit or a character limit (it works for documents with little text). Instead I tried inserting with insert_many() but to my knowledge this will not do the required task of only inserting documents if no match on id (sourceID) leaving exiisting documents with a match unchanged.

Are there any alternative solutions to reach my desired goal?

This is the code that I have written for the bulk insert:

```
bulk = pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder(events,ordered=False)
for doc in test:
    bulk.find({ "sourceID": doc["sourceID"] }).upsert().update({
        "$setOnInsert": doc
    })
response = bulk.execute()
```

'events' is the database that I am inserting to and 'test' is the array that I am trying to insert.

Comment: What exactly is your error? MongoDB has size limit of cca 16MB per document.

Comment: I don't get an error, the documents are just not inserted and it seems to be only those that have a a lot of text. The problem does not occur when I test with documents with short texts.

Comment: did you check mongo logs? how does the response object look like?